# Method to insert object at index (LinkedList)

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I am trying to create a method that replaces a specific object from my linked list by another object. replaceAtIndex(object, index).
I have no idea how to get a specified index from my linked list.

Here is the code for my linked list class:

```java
public class CellList {

    public class cellNode{
        private cellPhone phone;
        private cellNode next;
        
        //default null
        public cellNode() {
            phone = null;
            next = null;
        }
    
        //parametrized 
        public cellNode(cellPhone phone, cellNode next) {
            this.phone = phone;
            this.next = next;
        }
        
        public cellNode(cellNode x) {
            this.phone = x.phone;
            this.next = x.next;
        }
        
        //Cloning
        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            cellNode x=new cellNode(this.phone,this.next);
            return x;
        }

        public cellPhone getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public cellNode getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setPhone(cellPhone phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public void setNext(cellNode next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
        
    }

    private cellNode head;
    private int size;
    
    //default
    public CellList() {
        head=null;
        size=0;
    }

    //copy
    public CellList(CellList c) {
        this.head = c.head;
        this.size = c.size;
    }
    
    //Add a node at start
    public void addToStart(cellPhone c) {
        cellNode cn=new cellNode(c,head);
        head=cn;
        size++;
    }
```

I tried this method but it only correctly replace my elements if the index passes is less than 1.
If I try at index 3 for example, it won't replace anything at all and show me the normal list.
If I try an index that is higher than my size, it will throw the exception as expected.

```java
public void insertAtIndex(cellPhone c,int index) {
    if(index<0 || index>=size) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Out of boundary!!!");
    }
    else {
        if(index==0) {
            addToStart(c);
        }
        else if(index>0 && index<size) {
            cellNode curr=head.next;
            cellNode prev=head;
            cellNode cn=new cellNode(c,head);
            int i=1;
            while(curr!=null) {
                if(i==index) {
                    prev.next=cn;
                    cn.next=curr;
                    size++;
                    i++;
                    return;
                }
                prev=curr;
                curr=curr.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change `i` in the `while (curr != null)` loop.  If you add `i++`, it looks like it ought to work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your insight, unfortunately it doesn't work.
I made a mistake in my question, I wrote the wrong method.
I edited it if you want to take another look:)

Comment: I think you need to think about what `i++` means, why I suggested it, and where that means it should go.  (You haven't put it in the right place.)